# What is the default interpolator if android:interpolator is unspecified

Tags: android, android-animation

In Android, I know we can define animations via an XML file.

For example, `scale_button_up.xml` might look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
     android:fillBefore="true"
     android:fillAfter="true"
     android:fillEnabled="true">
    <scale
        android:duration="5000"
        android:fromXScale="0.25"
        android:fromYScale="0.25"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0.75"
        android:toYScale="0.75"/>
</set>
```

I was wondering what the default behavior is for Android version 21+

```
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
```

If the above were not specified. I can't seem to find the relevant documentation.

Comment: The default interpolator is `AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator`: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/lollipop-release/core/java/android/view/animation/Animation.java#803.

Comment: @MikeM. I would be happy to accept this as an answer if you posted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All `*Animation` classes are subclasses of `Animation`, and it handles setting the interpolator specified in XML attributes in its constructor. If there isn't one specified, the default [`AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator.html) is set in its `ensureInterpolator()` method.

```
/**
* Gurantees that this animation has an interpolator. Will use
* a AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator is nothing else was specified.
*/
protected void ensureInterpolator() {
    if (mInterpolator == null) {
        mInterpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
    }
}
```